# General question about Capacitor sizes in DC circuits

Tags: capacitor, dc

A general question -- let's say there is a DC circuit with a capacitor that needs to be replaced.  Can I use any capacitor that is at least as large or do I have to use one that is exactly like the original one?

Of course, for AC circuits, they have to match exactly because they determine frequencies, but in DC circuits I don't think it matters. Another way to ask the question is can anyone think of an application other than frequencies/filters where the capacitance cannot be too big?

Comment: I was going to say "power supplies", but that falls under "filters".

Comment: You should stick to the same value and same overall type (electro/tantalum/film/ceramic) in general. It could be there to provide a time delay for example.

Comment: If the circuit is truly DC, then you can remove the capacitor and it won't change anything. The capacitor is there to deal with some AC or transient behavior, though, so don't actually do this.

Answer (score 1):

Fully discharged capacitor will appear as dead short to anything that trying to charge it. The higher the capacitance, longer the time it will appear as shorted point to the power supply.

Thus, if you replace say a 1000uF with 68000uF in a power supply reservoir, and the overall impedance of the AC side is low enough, the main causality will be your rectifiers. It may not die immediately, but it will after some times due to very high inrush current. This depends on how many times the power cycling is done.

In high voltage DC application, huge capacitance will create hazardous voltage storage for longer than anticipated duration.

Another place where higher capacitance in DC circuit is not desirable is in timing applications. You may offset the original timing of the circuit by higher capacitance.

Comment: I'd like to add that with oversized capacitors even if the rectifiers are sturdy enough not to blow out, they pass the same energy as with a smaller capacitor, but they do so in less time. This will result in short high current spikes in the rectifier and transformer. These short spikes love to radiate and may stray into sensitive high impedance parts of a circuit. It's a common error of hobbyists to oversize filter-caps and wonder why their amplifier is buzzing.

Comment: Extra oversized filter caps will not cause buzz in amps if proper star grounding is practiced. Just don't let the ripple current in the 0 volt center tap of the transformer flow through the ground lines of the amp circuit.

Comment: It may do. The current spikes propagate back into the mains transformer which will then radiate the harmonics of the spikes out.

Comment: Bigger cap -> higher current -> stronger em fields -> more radiation.  Makes sense.  Any rules of thumb for the hobbyists?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the points made above, higher capacitance generally means a lower maximum voltage, so using a capacitor that's a lot larger means a much higher susceptibility to damage from stray voltages and ripple.

Comment: "higher capacitance generally means a lower maximum voltage,"... Can you explain this? I'm in dark after reading it.

Comment: @soosaisteven It means that if you have two capacitors for the same price or size, and one has a higher capacitance, it probably has a lower maximum voltage.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Generally speaking, capacitance is increased by putting the plates closer together, which allows more charge to be stored. However, this results in a lower breakdown voltage since there is less insulating material between the plates.